# how to fix 'SYSCALL execve': ls complains about a NULL argv[0]

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, x86, system-calls

I created my syscall but not found.
it's my code in asm

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
xor eax,eax

push eax
push dword '//ls'
push dword '/bin'
mov ebx,esp
mov al,0xb
int 0x80
;/bin//ls
```

When build a static 32-bit executable from this and run it, I get:

```
A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What's happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: Why two slashes in `//ls`?

Comment: `execve` requires 3 arguments: the path to the program, a pointer to a null-terminated array of argument strings, and a pointer to a null-terminated array of environment variable strings.

Comment: You only seem to be pushing 2 arguments. Also, the `argv` array should have the program name in the first element.

Comment: @Barmar Technically that's a single argument (`ebx` pointing to a region on the stack).

Comment: @barmar it doesn't matter how much // you put. Thank

Comment: thanks. i have solved, add params to ls.    section .text
global _start

_start:
xor edx,edx
push edx
push dword '/ls'
push dword '/bin'
mov ebx,esp

push dword '.'
mov ecx,esp
push edx
push ecx
push ebx
mov ecx,esp
xor eax,eax
mov al,0xb
int 0x80

Comment: daniel, you can write an answer to your own question if you want. I would upvote it...

Comment: @Barmar: Shellcode needs to avoid containing any `0` bytes, so to construct the string on the stack you need to pad it to a multiple of 4 bytes for 32-bit immediates to not contain a 0.  Or 4*n + 1 to push the last byte with a `push imm8` that gives the last bytes from zero padding.  Also, Linux system calls take their args in registers.  This is attempting to do `execve("/bin//ls", NULL, NULL)` which *is* supported in Linux as equivalent to passing pointers-to-NULL for empty argv and envp.  It doesn't bother to actually zero ECX or EDX so it depends on Linux doing that for a fresh process.

Comment: @Barmar: Passing the program name as `argv[0]` is a convention that most callers of `execve` follow, but it's not required and most programs (including `/bin/sh`) work without it.  But `ls` on my system complains about it, just like the OP shows, and then crashes.  You can see with `strace` that the execve system call executed correctly; it's `ls`'s decision / choice to crash when run that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as you intended, making an `execve("/bin//ls", NULL, NULL)` system call which succeeds.

**The problem is that GNU `ls`, unlike `sh` or some other programs, chooses to abort() when run with empty `argv[]`**.  The usual convention is to pass the program name as the first argument (`argv[0]`).

Your program works fine with `/bin//sh` instead of `ls`

---

Your argv and envp args to `execve` come from leaving ECX and EDX = 0, as Linux chooses to set them before entering user-space.  (This avoids kernel info leaks vs. leaving them uninitialized).  Obviously this won't work in shellcode which will run with registers holding unknown values.

BTW, Linux `execve()` [does document](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#NOTES) that it supports passing envp and/or `argv=NULL` instead of `argv = (char*[]){NULL};` (a pointer to NULL).  Instead of returning `-EFAULT` for an `argv` that doesn't point to valid memory, it special-cases NULL as an empty array.

---

I can reproduce your results on Arch Linux with `ls (GNU coreutils) 8.31`

```
$ nasm -felf32 exec.asm
$ ld -melf_i386 -o exec exec.o

$ ./exec 
A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

You can use `strace` to see for certain that the message isn't coming from your process.

```
$ strace ./exec 
execve("./exec", ["./exec"], 0x7ffd7090ed90 /* 54 vars */) = 0  <=== starting your program
strace: [ Process PID=21152 runs in 32 bit mode. ]

execve("/bin//ls", NULL, NULL)          = 0         <==== This is your system call
  # then ls starts up normally
strace: [ Process PID=21152 runs in 64 bit mode. ]
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55b5fbaff000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffe1d74c5b0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

 ... normal dynamically-linked executable startup stuff ...

 ... until it writes a message to stderr and raises SIGABRT ...
write(2, "A NULL argv[0] was passed throug"..., 55A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.
) = 55
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
getpid()                                = 21152
gettid()                                = 21152
tgkill(21152, 21152, SIGABRT)           = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=21152, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If you looked in `ls`'s source code you might see the `abort()` function call, especially if you search on the string it prints.

As I said, `bash` and most other shells don't do that.

---

If you did want to fix it, you might want to create an array of pointers `{"/bin//ls", NULL}` and pass a pointer to that as the 2nd arg.

```
    ...
    mov  ebx, esp     ; path

    push eax          ; 0
    push ebx          ; pointer to the filename
    mov  ecx, esp     ; argv = pointer to that array

    cdq               ; envp = EDX = 0 (broadcast high bit of EAX into EDX)

    mov  al, 0xb
    int  0x80
```

I added zeroing of EDX for good measure.

**That works for me: `ls` runs successfully.**